# Type Declarations in C ( Conceptual )

Tags: c, struct, type-declaration

This question is in general more of a conceptual question and not a coding problem essentially. I was curios as I came across these pieces of code and was wondering if they are valid or not. Or why basically , if someone could give me an explanation please ?

Here are some type declarations in C:

```
typedef struct Rec1 * Ptr1;
typedef struct Rec2 * Ptr2;

struct Rec1
{
    int data;
    Ptr2 next;
};

struct Rec2
{
    double data;
    Ptr2 next;
};
```

Should these be allowed? Are they allowed? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, this code is valid. What in particular do you have a question about?

Comment: What exactly is your question about? What exactly do you want explained? You posted some valid code, a rather basic one and asked why it is valid... It is like asking why 2+2 is 4. How can one answer such question? What exactly do you see as an issue that attracted your attention in this code?

Comment: @AndreyT - I had read this code in a book and it didn't say whether it was valid or not. I am recently learning about the structs and the way they can be declared , So I thought I would throw this question to the community and see what are the explanations !

Comment: @novice7 I am curious which book this is from?

Comment: Programming Languages : practices and principles @d0rmLife

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they valid?

## Yes they are valid

Reason:

1. First two lines create `Ptr1` and `Ptr2` as type-definitions for a `struct Rec1 *` and `struct Rec2 *`.
2. Since they are pointers, and not structures themselves, they make the `struct Rec1` and `struct Rec2` as incomplete types, and they are just making `Rec2` as recursive type (usually used in creating datastructures) and `Rec1` as having a pointer to `Rec2` object.

> Should they be allowed?

How else can you create self-referencing structures?

Comment: I don't understand point 2. The typedefs *are* declaring the struct types as incomplete ones.

Comment: It still seems incorrect. The line `typedef struct Rec1 * Ptr1;` is declaring an incomplete structure type: `Rect1`, and a complete pointer type: `Ptr1`. The fact that `Ptr1` is a pointer does not change the declaration of `Rec1`.

Answer (score 1):

The short version:

- Should it be allowed? Yes
- Are they (forward type type definitions)? Yes.
- Why or why not?

This is a commonly accepted way of doing forward type declaration.  It allows one to declare a incomplete type and define it later.  This isn't a big deal in simple cases like this, but can be absolutely necessary in cases that are more complex.

The Linux or Darwin kernel both make fairly extensive use of this technique to declare internal kernel structures in a way that allows definition of the data type in it's own header file, but allows the use of the data type before it's fully defined.

Without this mechanism complex, interdependent, definition of data types would be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

According to the language standard, they are valid and therefore should be allowed.

Now, if you ask how this all works, it's pretty easy.

Pointers are merely memory addresses, usually. And you can have a pointer to any object in memory if the object is represented by an integral number of bytes (each of which has a unique address). I'm saying "integral" here because you can't have a pointer to structure bit fields (at least, you can't have a pointer to those that don't begin on a byte boundary and occupy an integral number of bytes).

So, `Ptr2` is just a pointer type of a beforehand known size (if your CPU's address space is from 0 to 4 GB, 32 bits of address are sufficient to address every byte and 32 bits would be the native pointer size on this CPU) and you can allocate space for such a pointer in `struct Rec1` and `struct Rec2` even if what this pointer points to isn't yet known, which is what we have in the code in question. `Ptr1` and `Ptr2` are defined as incomplete types, that's the official name for this.

The rationale for implementing such incomplete pointer types in the language is very practical. If you want to create linked lists or trees, their elements or nodes have to point somehow to other elements or nodes they're linked with. You could, in theory, create distinct element/node types for the last element (or a leaf node) and then for the one that points to it and then for the one that points to that one and so on. But this doesn't scale well, if you have more than just a few elements or nodes. What if you want a million of them? Defining a million of nearly identical types is impractical at best. So, the language provides you with a short-cut to avoid this. You could also declare the `next` pointers as just `void*` pointers, but then you'd need to cast them everywhere to `struct Rect1*` or `struct Rect2*` and maintaining and debugging of such code is going to be error-prone. So, there, the language gives you a hand.

Comment: Could you explain the benefit the `typedef struct Rec2 * Ptr2` line has over, something like, saying `struct Rec2* next;` within the actual `struct` definition? Is there a benefit? I don't see it yet.

Comment: @d0rmLife `Ptr2` is less typing than `struct Rec2*` when you need one?

Comment: Lol. Touche. In the materials I have read about such data structures, the convention is to declare them as I commented above. So I was wondering if there was some feature this sort of `typedef` declaration gives--besides compactness, I suppose...!

Comment: @d0rmLife There isn't much else there, really.

Answer (score 0):

A typedef is just an alias for the actual type it refers to. You can think of it as a Macro, but it is not something which gets substituted in the pre-processing phase of compilation.

Just substituting all occurrences of **Ptr1** with **struct Rec1 *** yields a valid code, that is the simplest way to confirm if the code is valid ;)